Position items inside flex container using only css
I am working on a CSS file where I need to use flex to position the elements.
The elements should look like this:
======================================|--------|
            Header                    |        |    
======================================| edge-1 | 
     |                                |--------|
     |                                |        | 
Nav  |         Information            | edge-2 | 
     |                                |--------|
     |                                |        | 
     |                                | edge-3 |
======================================|        |
        Footer                        |        | 
=======================================--------|        

Details about the element size are:
• The left side container (Header, Nav, Information, Footer) needs 4/5 of the parent's width.
• The right side container (edges 1,2,3) needs 1/5 of the parent's width.

• The Nav needs 1/4 of the parent's width. 
• The Information needs 3/4 of the parent's width.
• The Header needs 1/5 of the parent's height.
• The Footer needs 1/5 of the parent's height.

I have below index.html file which is read only file:


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.elements {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.left-portion {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 4;
}

.right-portion {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.header {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.footer {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 3;
}

.nav {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.information {
  flex: 3;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.edge-1,
.edge-2,
.edge-3 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
<div>
  <div class="Holder">
    <div class="elements">
      <div class="left-portion">
        <div class="item header" data-title="header"></div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="item nav" data-title="nav"></div>
          <div class="item information" data-title="information"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item footer" data-title="footer"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="right-portion">
        <div class="item edge-1" data-title="edge-1"></div>
        <div class="item edge-2" data-title="edge-2"></div>
        <div class="item edge-3" data-title="edge-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="template">
      <div class="item item-1" data-title="header"></div>
      <div class="item item-2" data-title="nav"></div>
      <div class="item item-3" data-title="information"></div>
      <div class="item item-4" data-title="footer"></div>
      <div class="item item-5" data-title="edge-1"></div>
      <div class="item item-6" data-title="edge-2"></div>
      <div class="item item-7" data-title="edge-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



With this css I am able to align elements which are under div portion "Holder -> elements"
Now I was told to modify this css based on test case script:
  it.each([
    'header', 'nav', 'information', 'footer', 'edge-1', 'edge-2', 'edge-3'
  ])('verify element %s ', async (element) => {
    const elements = await driver.findElement(By.css(`.elements [data-title="${element}"]`))
    const template = await driver.findElement(By.css(`.template [data-title="${element}"]`))

    const eRect = await elements.getRect()
    const tRect = await template.getRect()

    const deviation = 2
    expect(Math.abs(tRect.y - eRect.y)).toBeLessThanOrEqual(deviation)
    expect(Math.abs(tRect.x - eRect.x)).toBeLessThanOrEqual(deviation)

    expect(Math.abs(tRect.width - eRect.width)).toBeLessThanOrEqual(deviation)
    expect(Math.abs(tRect.height - eRect.height)).toBeLessThanOrEqual(deviation)
  })

Here the test script needs the items which are under Div class "template" to be inside the flex container holder.
I am stuck here on how to modify the css without touching HTML and test scripts.

Flexbox seems to work if you correct the typo and give each element some actual content. Not sure what the "Template" is doing but hey-ho! = https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wvLKLKW?editors=1100

@Paulie_D, I need to make the test case script pass, so I need  to arrange the items in template div also inside holder div.

What does the template do? I'm assuming it generates the elements for you but what actual HTML does it output? And why does your given HTML have both the elements AND the template.

@Paulie_D, please check the test script, it shows more details

Not sure what details you think it shows. I don't understand the script...what do you think it does? What does it actually do that you think needs changing.

@Paulie_D, I want to place div with class item item-1 inside header of div with class item header using css

Well you can't do that with flexbox as its not in the same parent

For 2D layouts I prefer grid over flex.


.elements {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header sidebar" "nav info sidebar" "footer footer sidebar";
  gap: 2px;
  color: white;
}

.elements .left-portion, .elements .left-portion .content {
  display: contents;
}

.elements .header, .elements .nav, .elements .information, .elements .footer, .elements .right-portion {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.elements .header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.elements .nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background: orange;
}

.elements .information {
  grid-area: info;
  background: blue;
}

.elements .footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: pink;
}

.elements .right-portion {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
<div class="elements">
  <div class="left-portion">
    <div class="item header" data-title="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="item nav" data-title="nav">nav</div>
      <div class="item information" data-title="information">information</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item footer" data-title="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-portion">
    <div class="item edge-1" data-title="edge-1">edge-1</div>
    <div class="item edge-2" data-title="edge-2">edge-2</div>
    <div class="item edge-3" data-title="edge-3">edge-3</div>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you, but I have to use only flex to solve this instead of grid. Also I have to make the test case script pass, so I need to arrange the items in template div also inside holder div.
